# xamarin initializecompontent() nullReferenceException

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I'm pretty new at xamarin and I'm trying to read a value out of an editor/entry using MVVM but every time I launch the code and I open the page my initializer gives me a nullreferencexception. From what I think I know I should just bind the editor text to a value in my viewmodel and reference it in my xaml file (xmlns), even looking at the documentation and seeing other people doing it in example code and videos I don't seem to be able to fix this issue.

If anyone knows if I missed a step or don't understand something, it would be a massive help if you could inform me of this.

Thank you for your time and help.

this is what my xaml looks like:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:student_app.ViewModels"
             x:Class="student_app.Views.AddCategoryPage"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:student_app.Models" >
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:AddCategoryViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <RefreshView x:DataType="local:AddCategoryViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadCategoriesCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Add Category:"/>
            <Editor Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Width="300" Text="{Binding CategoryNameEditor}" Placeholder="enter category name"/>
            <Button x:Name="saveButton" Text="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </RefreshView>
</ContentPage>
```

this is what my code behind looks like:

```
namespace student_app.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class AddCategoryPage : ContentPage
    {
        AddCategoryViewModel _viewModel;
        public AddCategoryPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = _viewModel = AppContainer.Resolve<AddCategoryViewModel>();
        }


        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            _viewModel.OnAppearing();
        }
    }
}
```

viewmodel code:

```
namespace student_app.ViewModels
{
    public class AddCategoryViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private readonly IToastService _toastService;
        private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
        private readonly ICategoryService _categoryService;
        public string categoryName;

       
        public Command SaveCommand { get; }
        public Command LoadCategoriesCommand { get; }
        public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string CategoryNameEditor 
        {
            get => categoryName;

            set
            {
                categoryName = value;
                var args = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(nameof(CategoryNameEditor));
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
            }
        }
        public AddCategoryViewModel(IToastService toastService, INavigationService navigationService, ICategoryService categoryService)
        {
            _toastService = toastService;
            _navigationService = navigationService;
            _categoryService = categoryService;
            SaveCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteSaveCommandCommand());
            LoadCategoriesCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadCategoriesCommand());
        }

        public async Task ExecuteLoadCategoriesCommand()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            try
            {
                categoryName = string.Empty;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await _toastService.DisplayToastAsync(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }


        public async Task ExecuteSaveCommandCommand()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            try
            {
                _categoryService.addCategory(categoryName);
                categoryName = string.Empty;
                await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("CalanderPage");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await _toastService.DisplayToastAsync(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
        public void OnAppearing()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: first, you are setting the `BindingContext` in the XAML and in code.  Do not do this.  Pick one approach.  Second - you are getting a NullRef, you need to determine which specific line causes it, and then which element is null.  Look at the stack trace.

Comment: only thing in the stack trace i see is "[external code]" and the error itself says "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'", also I had added a lot of breakpoints ant it happens at the "initializecomponent()" in the code behind, I've also removed stuff and added it back until the error was gone and it only happens when the "editor" is added in. the double bindingcontext was due to me trying was other code showed as working and i forgot to remove the old one.

Comment: why does the editor have `Grid` properties when it is not enclosed in a Grid?  Why are you using `Width` instead of `WidthRequest`?

Comment: the row and collumn properties were because i was code from a video about mvvm in xamarin and i hadn't removed it yet, but the width was actually the issue, thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Generally, If you not getting anything on stack trace and you are getting this exception "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' especially at the time of view initialization like at the point of  `InitializeComponent()`  so first analyze your xaml code inside view that will be issue most of the time some control properties do not get caught at compile time and here also your problem lies inside your view itself. As @jason highlighted it. Width is the issue here Width will be a valid property in **wpf** but here in Xamarin forms it is an issue.